# Proper way to Include SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am just starting with mySQL, and have been through many of the tutorials, but there are a couple of things I cannot find.
**1:** Do you just include the following in your HTML, or would it go into a different file (if so, what would the extension be)?

```
CREATE DATABASE user_db;
    CREATE TABLE Users
    (
        UserNum int,
        LastName varchar(100),
        FirstName varchar(100),
        Address varchar(255),
        City varchar(255),
        ZipCode varchar(100),
        Phone int,
        MonthBorn varchar(100),
        DayBorn int,
        YearBorn int
  );
```

**2:** How would you create a database used by every page of your website, and never gets deleted (ex. for a user database)?

Comment: MySQL and HTML have nothing to do with each other.  You need a server-side language (like PHP, Python, Java, etc.) to talk to the MySQL database.  The SQL queries would go in your PHP (or whatever) files.  You don't need to create a new database for each page.  Different tables, possibly, but not different databases.  MySQL is actually a separate process that runs alongside your webserver.  It's not temporary storage.

Comment: Agree with @Rocket above, but would add that the table creation is something completely separate from the using of the website. You only create the backend tables once -- then you manipulate them using some other language (e.g., PHP, perl)

Comment: @MJB How would I create a database versus updating it? Would they both be in a PHP file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use mySQL with only HTML.  You need to use a server-side scripting language (such as PHP) to do your database work.  As for the second question, a database runs on a server where it can be accessed by any page (that is given permission to access it).  And the data would persist (never get deleted until you delete it). That's what a database is designed to do.  Check out some tutorials on the Google to get a handle on databases.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use a database in your web application, then you need to set up and configure the database, in this case.  MySQL would be running and you would use commands like that to create the tables within the database.  From there, pending on the language(s) your using, you have a plethora of options available for access.

Pretty good guide for using Active Records with Ruby on Rails:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Asp.Net has tons of options but works better with SQL Server versus mySQL:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access

You can't interact with a database directly with just html.  You'll need to use something like PHP, Ruby, C#, or even javascript on Nodejs to interact with the database.  If you wish to do user authentication and management, I suggest starting with a CMS (Content Management System) like WordPress or DotNetNuke.  They have plenty of starting out tutorials on how to set up your database, connecting to it and handle user authentication in a fairly secure manner.

Answer (score 0):

To answer both questions, I would look at mysqladmin for actions like creating databases and tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html

It's also useful for pretty much anything else you could want to do (testing queries, fixing errors, general maintenence)